# Partials not showing up in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, render, partials

I'm doing the ruby tutorial and I am currently on listing 5.9. The partials do not show up in my `app/views/layouts` directory

This is the code, I am using rails 1.8.7 on OSX 10.8. I'm using `rvm` and installed via brew install:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                                           "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render :partial =>'layouts/shim' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render :partial => 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I followed the tutorial exactly up to this point and every once in a while I need to adjust for using 1.8.7 instead of 1.9. The tutorial says to do

```
<%= render'layouts/header' %>
```

that didn't work so I tried

```
<%= render :partial => 'layouts/header' %>
```

and the partials still don't appear.

Comment: What file names are in your `layouts` folder?

Comment: application.html.erb

The render method is in that file as listed above

Comment: That's all that's there? So it won't find `layouts/header` then since it doesn't exist there. You need your `header` partial to be in `layouts/_header.html.erb`.

Comment: ooooohhh!! So I create the header and put in in my layouts?

Comment: Thank You! This makes a lot more sense

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem till I realised it should be `<%= render`

(I was using `<% render`)

Answer (score 3):

When doing partials, the partial must be either in the same folder as your "calling" `erb` file, or in a folder you specify. In addition, the name of the partial must begin with an underscore(`_`) in the directory.

So if `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` calls partial `shim` and `header`, you can call them like this:

```
<%= render :partial => "shim" %>
```

and

```
<%= render :partial => "header" %>
```

And you must have them in `app/views/layouts/_shim.html.erb` and `app/layouts/_header.html.erb`, respectively.

If a partial exists in a different folder than your "calling" `erb`, for example, `app/views/foo/_header.html.erb`, then you'd render it from `applications` as follows:

```
<%= render :partial => "foo/header" %>
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for. Thx.